# Помогите найти программу для базы данных, чтобы можно было графический выбирать поля из таблиц и делать выгрузки

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql

Всем привет. Подскажите программу для базы данных, в которой можно работать с ней без знания SQL , чтобы была возможность визуально выбирать поля из таблиц и делать выгрузки, желательно веб версия. С возможностью подключения к базе на PostgreSQL
Есть похожее в libreoffice, но он не подходит по некоторым параметрам.
Скажем так, чтобы человек не знающий SQL мог интуитивно все понять и делать отчеты, и выгрузки из базы.

Comment: [phpPgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org) - PostgreSQL [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net) - MySQL

Comment: Чем вам LibreOffice не угодил? То что там - это максимально приближенный к юзеру вариант визуального конструктора запросов, который еще не требует изучения SQL

Comment: Никто не говорит, что он не угодил. Просто ищем дополнительные варианты.

Comment: pgAdmin направлен больше на опытного пользователя. А мне нужен такой продукт, чтобы человек не понимающий SQL смог в нем разобраться.

Comment: https://www.sqlmanager.net/ru/products/postgresql/manager один знакомый препод просил поставить именно эту прогу, чтобы обучать студентов.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то access вполне позволяет подключаться к БД PostgreSQL(придётся повозиться), а так же в пользовательском интерфейсе создавать запросы без знания написания запросов SQL

Comment: Да, но желательно иметь веб версию данного приложения, и чтобы можно было развернуть приложение на сервере.

Comment: Ну, в таком случае, вам только с phpPgAdmin работать, человек выше в комментарии вам оставлял название. А вообще очень странно как вы хотите чтобы человек не знающий sql в визуальном редакторе вам отчёты делал и выгрузки. Здесь либо человека обучать, либо программисту поставить задачу написания программы или веб-интерфейса "шоб Галя нажала на кнопочку и у неё всё выгрузилось"